# При билде docker почему-то не видит команду ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker

Учу docker. Проблема такая. При билде docker почему-то не видит команду
`ENTRYPOINT ["/zhkh/entrypoint.sh"]`
Вот мой dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /zhkh

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install netcat -y
#RUN apk update && apk upgrade -y && apk add -y postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["/zhkh/entrypoint.sh"]
```

```
 => [zhkh_service_bot internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                             2.6s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 396B                                                                              0.0s
 => [zhkh_service_web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                             2.9s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 396B                                                                              0.0s
 => [zhkh_service_bot internal] load .dockerignore                                                                3.5s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [zhkh_service_web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                3.9s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [zhkh_service_web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8                                    2.7s
 => [zhkh_service_web internal] load build context                                                                1.1s
 => => transferring context: 2.88kB                                                                               0.1s
 => [zhkh_service_web 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:e829405b4bf065e5c4144b6e34592db242345b07a06c  0.0s
 => [zhkh_service_bot internal] load build context                                                                1.4s
 => => transferring context: 2.88kB                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [zhkh_service_web 2/7] WORKDIR /zhkh                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [zhkh_service_web 3/7] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install netcat -y                             0.0s
 => CACHED [zhkh_service_web 4/7] RUN pip install --upgrade pip                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [zhkh_service_web 5/7] COPY ./requirements.txt .                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [zhkh_service_web 6/7] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                             0.0s
 => [zhkh_service_web 7/7] COPY . .                                                                               1.7s
 => [zhkh_service_bot] exporting to image                                                                         5.2s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                           2.7s
 => => writing image sha256:fad27d3687facf11b20fbed4ded9e2d6ab9809f8a76a630501d6a9867ad530d6                      0.1s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/zhkh_service_web                                                               0.2s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/zhkh_service_bot
```

Comment: Это прогресс билда, почему-то нормально он сюда не копируется, прошу прощениия. После копирования билд заканчивается, то есть он не доходит до entrypoint

Comment: а с чего вы взяли что не доходит? `entrypoint` выполняется не при билде образа, а при его запуске, вы пыталь его запустить и проверить выполняется ли скрипт?

Comment: Да, выдаёт ошибку не найден файл или директория

Comment: А вы файл точно сохранили?
У вас и `ENV` не применяется. И вообще должно быть 9 шагов, а не 7

Comment: И запускаете вы похоже не `docker build`, у него другой вывод